# Apache server in Linux error forbidden access

Tags: python, django, apache, web, wsgi

I'm a beginner in web development. When I run Apache server give me this error in web page:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.20 (Unix) mod_wsgi/4.4.22 Python/2.7.11
```

I'm developing using Django 1.9.1 web app and use mode_wsgi with apache version 2. Here is my wsgi.py file :

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "newSite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and my httpd.conf :

```
WSGIScriptAlias /newsite "/home/hello/django/newSite/newSite/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "/home/hello/django/newSite"

<Directory "/home/hello/django/newSite/newSite/">
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Apache is usually configured to run as a regular user (the user is usually called nobody, apache, httpd or www-data, depending on your linux flavor, you should look at your httpd.conf to find out). 

Make sure this user can actually access your wsgi.py.

Comment: in my hhtpd.conf my user and group defined http <br>

Comment: i chang files owner with chown to http but steel give same error

Comment: Just because the file is owned by http doesn't mean http user can actually see all the way to the files location.

Comment: can you more expliain to me please ?

Comment: Lets say my user is called madwombat and I have a file /home/madwombat/project/document.txt that I want you to read. So, I go `chown kamrad:kamrad ~/project/document.txt`. But you still cannot read it because you do not have permissions to the project directory and cannot access anything in it. So to allow you to read the file I need to make sure you have permission to access the project directory and the madwombat directory and the home directory.

Comment: Find something to read about the UNIX permission system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks guys'
im succeed to run the server truely .
just change target directory permission to 775 and change the user and group in httpd.conf to my current user .
and for custom folder for sites root , change "DocumentRoot" of httpd.conf and set permission. 
sory for my english.
thanks again